# How can I stagger text in vim?

Tags: visual-block, multiple-lines

Given the following text:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

How can each line be shifted left/right an amount related to their line number?  Desired outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5
      1 2 3 4 5
        1 2 3 4 5
```

and

```
        1 2 3 4 5
      1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

I've tried setting up a macro with visual block mode with varying degrees of success, but I'd ideally like a one liner that lets me select a block and execute it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### vimscript option

For the result:

```
1 2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5
      1 2 3 4 5
        1 2 3 4 5
```

Next "commands" solves it:

```
:for i in range(6)|call setline(i, repeat(' ', (i-1)*2).getline(i))|endfor
```

For the result:

```
        1 2 3 4 5
      1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Not really sure about the "rule" :)

### Another option with "macro"

1. step one, create macro

   `qq:exe "normal ".((line('.')-1)*2)."I "`
2. step two apply to 2nd to the last row (visually select it first)

   `'<,'>norm @q`

### PS, as asked in comment

to make it work for other line range apart started from line 1:

```
:for i in range(5,9)|call setline(i, repeat(' ', (i-1)*2).getline(i))|endfor
```

[image]

Comment: Nice.  I've never heard of vim scripts before, so this is pretty cool.  I also modified your `range` call to get the second result: `for i in range(6)|call setline(i, repeat(' ', (5-i)*2).getline(i))|endfor`.  Only problem is the number of lines has to be hardcoded and start on the top of the file.  I'll keep searching for a way to do this using visual line mode, but definitely helps in the meantime.

Comment: Not necessary, It is possible to change it to operate on any line range.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show that to me?

Comment: well, have you looked into `:h range()`?

Comment: My dude, this is awesome.  I didn't know about `range` **OR** `:h`.  Can you show me how to learn about binding selections from VISUAL LINE mode?  It looks like they turn into `'<,'>`, but I'm not sure how to search for help on those characters.  Thanks again for this.

Comment: `:h visual.txt` then `/ '<,'>` . And just `:h` is a very good starting point.